# What logic has been used in excel to calculate VLookUp?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have following data in excel

```
       A               B        c
 1  Mucket 1         black      bucket 1
 2  bucket 2         blue       
 3  Belt wagon 1     gray       
 4  Belt wagon 2     green      
 5  spread  rot      white
 6  semi 1           red        
 7  semi 2           yellow
```

I tried following formula in excel

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B7,2,TRUE)
```

It gave a following answer

```
green
```

My query: why it was chosen `Belt wagon 2` row. it was not a match of the `bucket 1` approximate match is `bucket 2` but it will be chosen `Belt wagon 2` row   so i need if the `exact logic` value set as `TRUE`, how to calculate the VLOOKUP() formula in excel?
please suggest me that would be great.

Comment: If you use TRUE as the last parameter then your lookup list should be sorted (ascending): you can't use TRUE if the list is unsorted (or at least you can, but the result may be unpredictable)

Answer (score 0):

I Suppose it is binary search. because it require the list to be sorted.
and the result is also the same as binary search.

Belt wagon 2 is the middle, and Belt wagon 2 < bucket 1, so it compares semi 1 and then spread  rot. and they are less close then Belt wagon 2. so the reulst is Belt wagon 2

Answer (score 0):

First, approximate Lookup MUST be done on a Sorted list. Otherwise, Excel algorithm just make no sense.
Second, approximate means "first item bigger than" or "last item smaller than" depending on the sorted order.
For text data, I'm petty sure that the alphabetic order counts.

You must then find another way to compare your data if you want to return the "bucket 2" line...